# React Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `my-optional-property`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

source code

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

interface MyButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  "aria-label": string;
  "my-optional-property"?: boolean;
}

function MyButton(props: MyButtonProps) {
  console.log(props);
  return <Button {...props} aria-label={props["aria-label"]} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton aria-label="aria-label" my-optional-property={true}>
        button
      </MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error message is captured below.
[image]

there are so many questions and answers in stackoverflow, but I haven't found a proper solution.

Of course, I've checked params in console, but as above the type of 'my-optional-property' is boolean.

I don't know why this error is occured.

Full code is following
https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-dew-jnjex

Comment: It's boolean, not Boolean.

Comment: I changed boolean, but the warning is still occured.

Comment: Try changing `my-optional-property={true}` to `my-optional-property="true"`.

Comment: @SteveBack Sorry I have tried with no luck, let's wait for others' posts

Comment: @keikai I've solved it by deleting my-optional-property before passing param to Button class. Thank you always.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

interface MyButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  "aria-label": string;
  "my-optional-property"?: boolean;
}

function clone(obj: any) {
  if (obj === null || typeof obj !== "object") return obj;

  var copy = obj.constructor();

  for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
  }

  return copy;
}

function MyButton(props: MyButtonProps) {
  /*
  do what I want with my-optional-property. before passing parameter to Button
  */
  let buttonProps: ButtonProps = clone(props);
  delete buttonProps["my-optional-property"];
  return <Button {...buttonProps} aria-label={props["aria-label"]} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton aria-label="aria-label" my-optional-property={true}>
        button
      </MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've solved it by modifying delete property.